# how to use pjax and sweetalert confirmation to delete row in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, pjax, sweetalert

I use sweetalert to get confirm for delete rows from user, the code for confirmation is

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    var formClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $("form."+ formClass).submit(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
                title: "Do you want delete this item?",
                text: "",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'yes!',
                cancelButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
            function(isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Deleted!',
                        text: 'the item is deleted!',
                        type: 'success'
                    }, function() {


                        form.submit();



                    });

                } else {
                    swal("Cansel", "Not deleted :)", "error");
                }
            });

    });
});
```

and this code for use pjax to have an ajax request in laravel

```
$(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $("#pjax-container").css({"opacity": "0.3"});
    })
    $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $("#pjax-container").css({"opacity": "1"});
    })

    $(document).on('submit', 'form[form-pjax]', function(event) {
        $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
    });
```

And the html form is:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.comments.destroy',[$comment->id]) }}" class="inline-div comment-{{ $comment->id }}" method="post" form-pjax>
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-opt delete" id="comment-{{ $comment->id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

By this code i haven't an ajax request.

Instead of "form.submit();" What to write?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you don't need to use pjax for this at all. You can delete a record from database asynchronously, simply using an ajax request. Here is how I would go about doing this:

In the code below, when the user clicks on the delete link, an alert would be presented to him. If he confirms the delete action, then the function `deleteFromDB` would be called which is responsible for sending an ajax request to the server.

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    var formClass = $(this).attr('id');
    event.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "Do you want delete this item?",
        text: "",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            deleteFromDB(formClass);
        } else {
            swal("Cancel", "Not deleted", "error");
        }
    });

});
```

The mentioned function is defined as below:

```
function deleteFromDB(formClass) {
    var url = "http://example.com/delete/this/record";
    var form = $("form."+ formClass);
    var formData = new FormData();
    form.find("input[name]").each(function(index, input) {
        formData.append(input.name, input.value);
    });
    $.post(url, formData).done(function(data) {
        swal({
            title: 'Deleted!',
            text: 'the item is deleted!',
            type: 'success'
        });
    });
}
```

It finds all the inputs that have a name attribute and appends each to a `FormData` object. Then a post ajax request is sent to the server and when the request is done, another alert showing the success of deletion shows up.

**Pay attention** here not to show the success alert before deleting the record (as you were doing in the above code), because then if something goes wrong during the request, i.e. the record could not be deleted for some reason, you would be able to show that error to the user.